# not able to execute .sh file

Tags: installation, command-line, execute-command, .sh

I downloaded modelsim install file which contained .sh file in it -setup.sh
I did the following two things

1. Right click->properties->permision->allow executing file as program
   ->double clicked the setup.sh -> RUN. Nothing happened.  No error...nothing.
2. In terminal

   - cd /to the path of the setup.sh
   - `chmod -x setup.sh` ...nothing happened no error nothing. The cursor passd on to the next line
   - `./setup.sh` ...nothing happened.

I also tired `sh setup.sh` and `bash setup.sh`, still nothing happened.

Downloaded the whole file again still nothing happened

Contents of the setup.sh file are:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SCRIPT_PATH=`dirname "$0"`
export CMD_NAME="$SCRIPT_PATH/components/QuartusSetupWeb-13.0.1.232.run"
eval exec "\"$CMD_NAME\"" $@
```

Comment: What are the contents of your script?

Comment: [CODE]#!/bin/sh
export SCRIPT_PATH=`dirname "$0"`
export CMD_NAME="$SCRIPT_PATH/components/QuartusSetupWeb-13.0.1.232.run"
eval exec "\"$CMD_NAME\"" $@[/CODE]

Comment: Can you edit that into your question with the proper formatting? It's hard to read and understand in a comment.

Comment: im not able to edit it

Comment: There is an edit button right below the tags on your question

Comment: i have put the code in the question

Comment: Your chmod is wrong. It should be `chmod +x setup.sh`

Comment: sorry .. there was a mistake in the question... but i have been using chmod +x

Comment: sometimes these applications need java to run. make sure you have it. Happened to me twice.

Comment: Normally if you run a command and get no output, just another prompt, it means the command ran and exited without printing output. So it sounds like the script *did* run, but didn't do anything visible. Perhaps the installer `QuartusSetupWeb-13.0.1.232.run` quit unexpectedly. Did you ever find a solution? If the script was not marked executable (`-x` takes executable permissions away) then you should have gotten an error message, not nothing. This appears to be abandoned and, although some people have tried, I don't think it can really be answered based on the information available.

Answer (score 4):

`chmod -x setup.sh` is used to take out the execute permission for the script. The right way to give execute permission for the script is:

```
chmod +x setup.sh
```

See [`man chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

Another thing: because of `$@`, probably your script expects one or more arguments. Check in the same directory where the script is, maybe you have there a `README` file  to see the right usage. Or try to search for install instructions from where you downloaded it.

Comment: Again you have mentioned the same command without changing `-x` to `+x`.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the file manager,
2. Go to Edit->Preferences,
3. On the Behavior-tab under "Executable Text Files"-section set the option to

   1. "Run executable text files when opened" or "Always ask"

Close it and try double clicking the file again

Comment: This fully depends on the file manager in use, OP didn't even name a specific file manager and neither did you.